# Algorithm / Number format for "less storage taking" numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, math, storage, discrete-mathematics

I have very serious problem to address. I have a list of 75000 words. Each word is assigned with a number for easy identification. First word is assigned with 0, last word is assigned with 75000. Now, I have a list of sentences. Lets take 1 sentence for an example.

```
I have big dog
```

When you represent this with assigned numbers, it become `20 123 2332 3434`. This simply means that word ***I*** appeared as the 20th word in our list, word ***have*** appeared as the 123 word in our list, word ***big*** appeared as the 2332 word and so on.

Just like this, I have more than 2 billion sentences, and I need to save/write their numerical representation. We felt that saving long numbers like `20 123 2332 3434` for 2 billion records will take a huge space. Instead, if we can represent them using a shorter number system like `F3x G6e rRr` it will save our storage space.

How can I achieve this? May be using Hexadecimal numbers? I used [this](http://www.statman.info/conversions/hexadecimal.html) converter and it seems  there is no much difference because number **123456** in hexadecimal is **1e240** number **75000** in hexadecimal is **124f8** and so on; seems like the number of characters are the same, so I am not sure whether it is going to save any space.

Please provide me your advice to achieve this task. I will be writing this function in Java.

Comment: How about Base64 and then Deflate?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Thank you for the reply. Any link to a reasonable source or something please?

Comment: Are you storing the list of numbers as a string or in binary format? If it's in binary format you could use a very simple convention, i.e., serialize the string as a 32 bit integer representing the number of words following and then one number per word serialized as a 17 bit integer (log2(75000)~17). You could even use some form of compression if you knew the distribution of the words upfront.

Comment: PS: in his [Algorithms](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) book, Robert Sedgewick describes methods to do things like that.

Comment: PPS: Take a look at his `BinaryIn` and `BinaryOut` classes in his [code section](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/). Furthermore, he describes compression techniques that I mentioned.

Comment: What about by starting off with not storing the actual numbers in a `String`? Then `int` would for example already be quite a good candidate. Also whether or not the number is literal or writtten in hex-notation does not matter then.

Comment: @skiwi: I didn't get you.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: I store in String.It is stored into a `HashMap` first. If I store as a binary then it would be something like `0010` right?

Comment: No, you have to store the raw bytes, not strings. Otherwise you're dead in the water.

Comment: do these words have any particularity?, does calculating then saving them will be better than checking weather a sentence is one of them, by testing it towards their logic?

Comment: Is there a shortage of space, generally speaking?

Comment: @groovy: No, but it will be amazon, so you have to pay

Answer (score 4):

Decimal numbers give you 10 possibilities per byte. Hexadecimal numbers give you 16. If you could use all possible bit-patterns, you would have 256 possibilities per byte, equivalent to storing two hex digits in the space of one. Depending on how you store and retrieve your data, you may find that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 encoding avoids corruptions if e.g. you cannot store zero bytes, or some other bit patterns, such as bit patterns with the high bit set.

There are possibilities for more sophisticated compression. One would simply to use a standard compressor, such as that provided in Java by package java.util.Zip, or equivalents in other languages. Another - if you know how common words are, would be to simply sort the words so that common words have low numbers, and therefore shorter numbers. You could also look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding. This would allow you to avoid having spaces between the numbers, and would also give shorter words shorter sequences of digits.

Comment: Hi, for an example, that means the hexadecimal representation of the word **big** (91c) takes less space than its numeric representation (2332) ? You get `91c` when you convert `2332` into hexadecimal.

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess sure, because the amount of space depends on the number of symbol you will have meaning 75000 having 5 symbols will take 5 bytes, while it's value in base 64 will have less symbols(3 if to be more precise)

Answer (score 1):

Implement a binary representation of your string. The first 16/32 bit represent the length of the string *n*, then follow *n* 17 bit integers representing the indexes in your array of 75000 words. The number 17 is roughly the logarithm in base 2 of 75000. So your example will become (assuming 16 bit for word length):

```
 0000 0000 0000 0100   0 0000 0000 0001 0100   0 0000 0000 0111 1011   
|                  4 |                    20 |                   123 | 
                       0 0000 1001 0001 1100   0 0000 1101 0110 1010 
                     |                  2332 |                  3434 |
```

Then you can convert that stream of bits to/from a binary file using for example Robert Sedgewick's [`BinaryIn` and `BinaryOut` classes](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/). Note that the string above now only requires 21 bytes to be encoded.

You could use Huffman compression to compress the binary stream if you knew the distribution of the words beforehand. This could save a lot of space if the distribution is skewed towards a small subset of the words.